# Can't connect Kubernetes pod to RDS Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds

I have a frontend application running in a Kubernetes cluster in AWS. It communicates with a Postgres RDS instance running in the same VPC. The RDS and the k8s worker nodes are both attached to the same private subnets.

The RDS security group allows all access from the Kubernetes nodes (EC2 instances) to the database. The connection from the *nodes* is fine, because running `telnet <rds-endpoint> 5432` returns `Connected to <rds-endpoint>.`

However when the application is deployed to the pods, it is unable to access the RDS instance. The pods are running on the nodes private IP address `<private-ip-address>:8080`. The worker node security group also allows all outbound traffic.

I think it may be a port forwarding issue but I do not have much visibility on the connectivity issues. Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mention how did you provision your kubernetes cluster.

1. Either you use EKS service. In that case, the pod IP address is really a secondary IP address of your EC2 instance (worker node). At least if you use default AWS CNI plugin All that should be needed in that case is really to allow EC2 intance ID in the security group attached to RDS.
2. You setup your cluster by yourself using `kubeadm` or something like that and you're using some CNI plugin like calico, flannel or weave. This creates the problem because POD IP addresses are not routed in your VPC. They are completely different from EC2 instance address. What you need to do in this case is setup address translation rule that you will translate source address of pod to IP address of EC2 instance. Follow this guide in that case: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/ip-masq-agent/

Comment: Hi - apologies. The cluster is set up in terraform using EKS. Will I need to allow inbound access from the instance itself? I believe you can only allow access from a CIDR range or a security group ID? I added inbound access on the RDS security group from the EC2 security group but that still does not work.

Comment: in that case you have two security groups: 1. one applied to your k8s worker nodes 2. applied to RDS - I think it should be enough to put the first security group ID into the second one + appropriate RDS port (depending on DB engine). Apparently you already di it. Some troubleshooting steps I'd take 1. ensure they really run in same VPC / subnet 2. recheck security group (outbound rule on first one, inbound on second one) 3. allow VPC CIDR on second one security group as source (to see if problem is related to SG ID used as source)

Comment: https://dev.to/bensooraj/accessing-amazon-rds-from-aws-eks-2pc3#setup-the-eks-cluster - this is something similar but in the example he uses two VPCs (one for k8s, other for RDS so he had to allow first VPC CIDR as source in RDS SG (third step from my previous comment)

Comment: I'd also try deploying i.e. `busybox` pod into your k8s cluster. use `kubectl exec -it -n my-namespace my-busybox-pod -- /bin/sh` and then do the troubleshooting directly from the pod. Maybe problem is with DNS resolution if you use FQDN for RDS endpoint.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I have the same issue. From the nodes, i am able to connect to db but from the pods, application is unable to (get i/o timeout error)